# Dynamic placeholder text in 'Plain text' field type

Tags: fieldtypes, dashboard

I have a plain text field that encourages content editors to write a more detailed description of a piece of content.

However, on the front-end the template will use the post title by default if this is not supplied.

I would like the placeholder text for this optional plain text field to represent the reality of this in the Dashboard - i.e. to display the title field as the placeholder if the field has not otherwise been used.

When editing the field, I have tried setting the 'Placeholder Text' as `{title}`, but this does not work - it displays "{title}"!

Is this possible? I don't want to create a new custom type of field as it seems a little heavy handed for this use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When editing the field, I have tried setting the 'Placeholder Text' as {title}, but this does not work - it displays "{title}"!

Yeah, those placeholder text fields aren't dynamically parsed as Twig templates like others (Entry URL Format, etc.).

> I don't want to create a new custom type of field as it seems a little heavy handed for this use case.

Unfortunately that's all that is coming to mind for me for this use-case.

Comment: Thanks Brad. Is it possible to create such a field that still stores the data exactly as it would if it was a regular text field? i.e. so if I switched it from my custom field back into a 'regular' text field, I wouldn't loose all my values in the DB?

Comment: Assuming the custom field uses the same type and size datatype in the database, the conversion should happen automatically.